# Trying to change 2 images average pixel brightness to a middle value (between them) using PIL in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have 2 images, I have calculated the average pixel brightness for both, I have then calculated the midpoint between the average brightness and the factors necessary to modify each image to reach tis "target" midpoint.

However, when I run the factor through the ImageEnhance (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html) function the modified image does not match the target midpoint. Not sure why. Images are attached.

Here is my code showing how I calculate the average brightness for each image and how I calculate the midpoint/factor and try to enhance the image, is there something wrong here or is this an issue with Pillow?

```
def calculate_average_brightness(image):
    """
    Calculate the average saturation value of an image.
    """
    brightness = 0
    pixels = image.convert('L').getdata()
    total_pixels = len(pixels)
    brightness = []
    for pixel in pixels:
        brightness.append(pixel)
    average_brightness = sum(brightness) / total_pixels
    return average_brightness, brightness

img1_path = os.path.join(path, "face_ai_midjourney (278).jpg")
img2_path = os.path.join(path, "face_real (10).jpg")
img1 = Image.open(img1_path)
img2 = Image.open(img2_path)


img1_bright, brightness = calculate_average_brightness(img1)
img2_bright, brightness_2 = calculate_average_brightness(img2)
mid = (img1_bright + img2_bright)/2
factor1 = mid/img1_bright
factor2 = mid/img2_bright

obj = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img1)
a = obj.enhance(factor1)

img1_bright2, brightness2 = calculate_average_brightness(a)
```

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q6Wx.jpg)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7VPy.jpg)

I checked to see if the issue was that the pixels were either maxing out at 255 after adjustment or minning out at 0, however for img1 (which is being upped, the max pixel after factor adjustment is still below 255).

Not sure what else could be happening (is it simply due to rounding issues? I wouldn't expect the difference from midpoint to be so large if that is the case)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what possessed you to write a `for` loop to calculate image brightness, nor why you would want to create a Python list of a quarter of a million pixels. In order to calculate the mean, you just need a running total in a single `float` variable and then divide by the number of elements at the end.

But in fact, you can do miles better by using the built-in `ImageStat` module to calculate statistics:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageStat, ImageEnhance

img1_path = "0Q6Wx.jpg"
img2_path = "O7VPy.jpg"
img1 = Image.open(img1_path)
img2 = Image.open(img2_path)

# Calculate mean brightness of greyscale versions
mean1 = ImageStat.Stat(img1.convert('L')).mean[0]
mean2 = ImageStat.Stat(img2.convert('L')).mean[0]
```

That gets me 28.6 and 32.1 as results, and if I apply the brightness enhancement:

```
mid = (mean1 + mean2)/2
factor1 = mid/mean1
factor2 = mid/mean2

im1enh= ImageEnhance.Brightness(img1).enhance(factor1)
im2enh= ImageEnhance.Brightness(img2).enhance(factor2)
```

and test the result, I see the brightness of the first has increased and that of the second decreased:

```
ImageStat.Stat(im1enh.convert('L')).mean
[29.977596282958984]
ImageStat.Stat(im2enh.convert('L')).mean
[29.97873306274414]
```